# DOM condicional números negativos en rojo

Tags: jquery, html5, asp.net, dom

Estoy ocupando webmethods ASP.NET. Cuando los datos regresan del servidor, refresco los labels HTML a través del jQuery DOM. Necesito construir un condicional el cual cambie estos labels a color rojo si es negativo y al verde si es igual o mayor a cero.

Éste es el código que tengo:

```
function OnSuccess(response) {                 
    document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleEvo.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[1];
    document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleEvo.ClientID %>').style.color = "#00B050"; 

    document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleEvo_p.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[2];
    document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleEvo_p.ClientID %>').style.color = "#00B050"; 
}
```

Comment: ¿Son `response.d[1]` y `response.d[2]` los valores numéricos?

Comment: si señor,  asp.net manda a través de un webmethod una variable de tipo string array, y en el jquery lo extraigo con response.d[1], [2], [3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inténtalo así:

```
var count = -2;
document.getElementById('<%=lbDetalleEvo_p.ClientID %>').style.color = (count> 0)? "#000": "#FF0000";
```

Comment: Gracias.. funciona bien